# When I scroll my web page, audio box just passes over the navigation bar, how to fix this issue. I don't want to show it on navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, audio

This is the code I am using. Also please tell, When anyone click the image which start the music will change while playing and again change image when stop playing.

```
        <img id="startOrStopImg1" class="audioimage" src="short images/cdd.png" alt="চালু করুন">
        <audio id="audio" src="short images/riya.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls>Your browser does not support the
            audio element</audio>

    This is the code I am using. Also please tell, When anyone click the image which start the music will change while playing and again change image when stop playing.
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the CSS property `z-index`! Higher index brings the element closer to the top.